# Flexbox works alright on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I developed my portfolio website on Google Chrome, and everything looked alright on it. This is what my "About" page looks like on Chrome:
[image: webpage on Chrome]

I checked Firefox to see if everything looked alright on that as well, but it didn't. This is what my "About" page looks like on Firefox:
[image: webpage on Firefox]

I've included my code below, but just to give a summary of the content, there is an `about-container`, which is a column flexbox. It contains `about-title` and `about-content`. `about-content` is another column flexbox and it holds an `about-table` which contains the text and the picture, and a `card` which holds my contact information.

Is there something wrong with my flexbox? Why does it work on Chrome but not on Firefox?

```css
#about-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.about-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #374457;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0.35em;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.about-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.about-content p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

.about-content .about-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div id="about-container">
  <div class="about-title">About Me</div>
  <div class="about-content">
    <div class="about-table">
      <div style="padding-right: 5em;">
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... TRUNCATED</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img id="header-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
      <be>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="card-title">Contact Information</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-date">Get in touch with me</div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-details">
          <div class="normal-text">
            <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0px; margin-left: 0px; line-height: 250%;">
              <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="mail circular icon"></i> loremus99@gmail.com</li>
              <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="linkedin circular icon"></i><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/loremus99/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> /in/loremus99/</a></li>
              <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="facebook circular icon"></i><a href="https://www.facebook.com/lorem1999" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> /lorem1999</a></li>
              <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="instagram circular icon"></i> _lorem</li>
              <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="snapchat ghost circular icon"></i> loremus99</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: without the actual rendering code it is hard to tell your code shared does not mean anything

Comment: Sorry, updated.